# Getting Wget and JQL to run

Tags: jira, wget, jql

We are trying to run a command wget -O xyz.xls --user=COldPolar --password=GlacierICe --ignore-length=on "http://Colder.near.com:8080/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/temp/SearchRequest.xls?&runQuery=true(jqlQuery=project%3DCCD)&tempMax=1000"

This is returning a 3kb output

If we open IE and use the following "http://Colder.near.com:8080/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/temp/SearchRequest.xls?&runQuery=true(jqlQuery=project%3DCCD)&tempMax=1000" This allows us to save a 1.7MB file. Please advise how to get the wget to work

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `cURL` you can do:

```
curl -o xyz.xls -u COldPolar:GlacierICe 'http://Colder.near.com:8080/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/temp/SearchRequest.xls?&runQuery=true(jqlQuery=project%3DCCD)&tempMax=1000'
```

What I managed to get `wget` to work was to do this first:

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'os_username=COldPolar&os_password=GlacierICe&os_cookie=true' http://Colder.near.com:8080/login.jsp
```

And then:

```
wget -O xyz.xls --load-cookies cookies.txt "http://Colder.near.com:8080/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/temp/SearchRequest.xls?&runQuery=true(jqlQuery=project%3DCCD)&tempMax=1000"
```

Comment: Thanks Welsh:- I tried Curl and getting the error "X-Seraph-LoginReason: AUTHENTICATED_FAILED", I will dig futher and see. Also trying to use jcli for the same.

Comment: If you are getting `X-Seraph-LoginReason: AUTHENTICATED_FAILED` then it is because your credentials aren't valid for the instance you are interacting with.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things to watch out for is a self-signed certificate. You can rule this out by running with --no-check-certificate.